# Stack release version number restrictions

Tags: ros, ros-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When reading about the release process I've found the following note:

*Note: You can release the same version into two different distros, but it must be exactly the same. If you need to have minor differences please use different numbered series. Something like 1.2.x vs 1.3.x for electric and fuerte.*

http://www.ros.org/wiki/release/Setup/Repository

I'd like to know if this is mandatory, and what is the reason if it is.

We have slightly different versions of our stack for fuerte and groovy, but we'd like to stick with what we think is a more reasonable versioning scheme (major.minor.revision) and we'd like to release with the same version number for both ROS distros, as the debian packages generated contain the distro name, so they won't collide (ros-fuerte-our-stack, ros-groovy-our-stack).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54594/stack-release-version-number-restrictions/) by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason is that the release script tags the versions within the VCS (see [octomap_mapping](http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2Fstacks%2Foctomap_mapping) for example). With a subsequent release of different code for the same version, the previous one will be overwritten, causing future builds of the previously tagged version to fail. The debian packages themselves will be fine, but there will be all kinds of nasty surprises in the build process (I've been there...).

If your code is built with "rosmake" (=rosrelease-legacy), you can actually use four digits. I have used that in the past to differentiate between identical version which only differed in the release distro (e.g. depending on different stacks). So there was e.g. 1.2.0 for electric and 1.2.0.1 for fuerte.

When releasing with catkin and bloom, there is a debian-increment number that could be used for that, so the version is 1.2.0 while the released debian package has version 1.2.0-1 and 1.2.0-2.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on 2013-02-07**:
Could this be solved by using release-tag: $RELEASE_NAME-$STACK_NAME-$STACK_VERSION instead of release-tag: $STACK_NAME-$STACK_VERSION in the .rosdistro files?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-02-07**:
Should definitely be worth a try!

**Comment by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on 2013-02-07**:
The release_tag trick doesn't solve everything. The branch is correctly tagged in our git repo, but when running the release script for fuerte I get a "svn: warning: 'sr_ronex-0.9.0.yaml' is already under version control". So there is a collision with a file generated when releasing for groovy.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-02-11**:
That's just a warning.  It's just letting you know that there's already a release with that number.  It's fine if you're intending to release the same version into both distros.  It's not ok if you forgot to increment the version or something like that.